# specified network name is no longer available - admin shares

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, server-message-block

I have a win2k12r2 SharePoint server, I cannot access its admin shares c$ admin$.

SMB 1.0/CIFS installed,
SMB2 enabled
Can ping, and resolve hostname
UDP ports 137 not open and 138 not, and TCP ports 139 open and 445 open.  this is the same result as for our other servers with accessible admin shares.
UAC enabled (tried disabling)

this was all working until recently after these patches were installed.

- [https://support.microsoft.com/help/5023790](https://support.microsoft.com/help/5023790%C2%A0)  Security Update               KB502379
- [https://support.microsoft.com/help/5023765](https://support.microsoft.com/help/5023765%C2%A0%C2%A0)   Security Update               KB502376

We're all stumped, we haven't tried rolling back patching to see if it would fix it, but was hoping there's something else we can look at.

Also in the event logs, every attempt to access the admin shares produces this event